# variable wont save in same function jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to sum dynamically created inputs but when i delete some of the inputs just to subtract its value from the var.and when i alert the variable current its NaN

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  current = 0;
  var max = 3;

  $(".inputs").on('keyup', '.field', function(e) {
    if ($('.field').val()) {
      current = current + parseInt($(this).val());
      if (current < max) {
        $(".inputs").append('<div><input type="text" class="field" name="dynamic[]" value="" /></div>');
      }
      if (e.keyCode == 8) {
        current = current - parseInt($(this).val());
        console.log(current);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form>
    <div class="inputs">
      <div>
        <input name="dynamic[]" id="field" class="field" value="" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <input name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" type="button">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, then you're trying to use `parseInt` on a non-number. Likely culprit is an empty input: `parseInt('')` yields `NaN`.

Comment: and can you tell me how to do it

Comment: `var val = $(this).val(); current -= isNaN(val) || val==""? 0: parseInt(val,10);` and never call anything in a form `name="submit"` if you have plans using the submit event

Comment: still cant make it to work with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is what you want, but it fixes your NaN
It does add to the current on any keyup though

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  current = 0;
  var max = 3;

  $(".inputs").on('keyup', '.field', function(e) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    val = isNaN(val) || val == "" ? 0 : parseInt(val, 10);
    current = current + val;
    if (current < max) {
      $(".inputs").append('<div><input type="text" class="field" name="dynamic[]" value="" /></div>');
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 8) {
      current -= val;
    }
    console.log(current);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form>
    <div class="inputs">
      <div>
        <input name="dynamic[]" id="field" class="field" value="" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <input name="mySubmit" class="submit" value="Submit" type="button">
  </form>
</div>
```

Perhaps you MEANT to do this:

```js
function getInt(str) {
  return isNaN(str) || $.trim(str) == "" ? 0 : parseInt(str, 10);
}
var total = 0,
  max = 3;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".inputs").on('keyup', '.field', function(e) {
    var val = getInt($(this).val());
    total = 0;
    $(".field").each(function() {
      total += getInt($(this).val());
      if ($(this).val() =="") $(this).remove();
    });
    console.log(total);
    if (total > 0 && total < max) {
      $(".inputs").append('<div><input type="text" class="field" name="dynamic[]" value="" /></div>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form>
    <div class="inputs">
      <div>
        <input name="dynamic[]" id="field" class="field" value="" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <input name="mySubmit" class="submit" value="Submit" type="button">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: if i got first input value=1 and second input value = 2 and delete the first input for example,current must become value =2;

Comment: Why not just add all input values?

Comment: Exactly what i meant but it doesnt stop to generate inputs on max value

Comment: Yes it does now :)

Comment: Yes but you misunderstood me.Max value is not the count of the inputs but the sum of the values of the input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126010/discussion-between-sebastian-jeliazkov-and-mplungjan).

Comment: Have a look at the second version again

Comment: Exactly what i want just need to restrict on 0 to not remove all the inputs and left one :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to check to make sure that `parseInt` doesn't fail:

```
// check for native isNaN:
if (!Number.isNaN) {
  Number.isNaN = function(n) {
    return n !== n;
  };
}

var num = parseInt($(this).val(), 10); // always provide radix to parseInt

if (!Number.isNaN(num)) {
  current += num;
}
```

Another (although not sufficient) way to help validate the input is to change the input type from text to number.

Comment: @mplungjan Number.isNaN !== window.isNaN.... former is more accurate but no IE support https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN

Comment: Ah, right. Never saw that construct before. Why replace window.isNaN with ES6 and a polyfill? What is the benefit?

Comment: @mplungjan `window.isNaN` returns true for *all* non-number values, `Number.isNaN` *only* returns true for the specific value `NaN`. In this case the difference is irrelevant but the behavior of the old one can be a little surprising.